# Django - Query for posts along with it's number of replies?

Tags: python, django

So I'm trying to populate a news feed with posts of a certain category. Then I want to be able to display the number of replies on the post. The reason I'm confused on how to do this, is because I filtered through goals by category then I filtered all the posts associated with all those goals and now I have a list of a dictionary containing the post body and goal description and create date, but I'd like to also add in the number of replies and I'm not sure how to do this in an efficient way. Also I realize my way of doing things in the view.py is less than ideal so any suggestions would be great!

Model.py

```
class Post(AbstractBaseModel):
    creator_id = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_creator_id")
    goal_id = models.ForeignKey(Goal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=511, validators=[MinLengthValidator(5)])
    hash_tags = models.ManyToManyField(HashTag)

class ReplyPost(AbstractBaseModel):
    creator_id = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="reply")
    post_id = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

View.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_most_recent_posts_by_category(request, category, count):
    goals_list = list(Goal.objects.filter(category = category).values_list('uuid', flat=True))
    data = list(Post.objects.filter(goal_id__in=goals_list).order_by('created').values('body', 'goal_id__description', 'created'))
    data['goal_description'] = data['goal_id__description']
    data['post_body'] = data['body']
    del data['goal_description']
    del data['body']
    return JsonResponse(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Count('replypost')` to add the number of items:

```
from django.db.models import Count

data = list(
    Post.objects.filter(
        goal_id__in=goals_list
    ).order_by(
        'created'
    ).values(
        'body', 'goal_id__description', 'created', replies=Count('replypost')
    )
)
```

Comment: awesome! If you look at my view.py you'll notice there's a count parameter coming in. Is there a way to get the k most recent posts then get the values as described?

Comment: also when calling .values() is there a way to set the dict keys to a custom key? As you see in my above post I'm just resetting then deleting it.

Comment: @user8714896: you can work with slicing by using `[:k]` after the `.values(...)` call (with `k` a variable that contains the number of items. You should also work with `.order_by('-created')` to sort in *decending* order.

Comment: How does Django know to count the replyposts with this post_id? I assume there's some kind of join going on behind the scenes here.

Comment: @user8714896: in the query it makes a `Count(replypost.id)` with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the `replypost` and a `GROUP BY` on `post.id`.